# How to prove that $ \max_{i=1,2}\{ |X_{i}^{\top}\theta| \}\geq a\delta $ where $ a=(|x_{1}-x_{2}|)/(4\max\{1,|x_{1}|,|x_{2}|\}) $?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

It is known that $ \| \theta\|_{2}\geq \delta>0 $ and $ \theta\in\mathbb{R}^{2} $. Let $ X_{i}=(1,x_{i})^{\top},i=1,2, $ where $ x_{1}\neq x_{2} $ and $ x_{1},x_{2}\in\mathbb{R} $. How to prove that the following inequality is true: $ \max_{i=1,2}\{ |X_{i}^{\top}\theta| \}\geq a\delta $ where $ a=(|x_{1}-x_{2}|)/(4\max\{1,|x_{1}|,|x_{2}|\}) $?

Comment: How about $\delta = 1, \theta_1 = -1, \theta_2 = 0, x_1 = 1, x_2 = -4$?

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks for your example. I think $ a $ should be $ a=(|x_{1}-x_{2}|)/(4\max\{1,|x_{1}|,|x_{2}|\}) $, then the inequality establishes in your example.

Comment: Simply observation: We only need to prove the case $\theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2 = \delta^2$. Let $\theta_1 = \delta \cos u, \theta_2 = \delta\sin u$ for $0\le u \le \pi$. The case $|X_1^\mathsf{T}\theta| = |X_2^\mathsf{T}\theta|$ is of interest.